# How can I restrict User role assignment using CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, cancan

Using a combination of a few tutorials and screencasts to set up Rails and CanCan to work with Devise etc. I've established `User`, `Role`, and the `UserRole` joining model for the `has_many :through` connection. And I only want some users to be able to assign certain roles, or create new accounts with those roles, etc.

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities), I feel like this should be pretty straightforward. What I have is essentially this:

```rb
if user
  if user.role? 'admin'
    can :manage, User
  elsif user.role? 'submanager'
    can :manage, User, roles: { name: ['basic', 'premium'] }
  end
else
  can :create, User, roles: { name: ['basic'] }
end
```

And then I'd simply test it in the form with:

```
- if can? :create, User, roles: { name: 'admin' }
    = check_box 'user[role_ids]', 'admin'
```

Or, at least, that's the gist. And trust me I've tried every combination of singulars, plurals, `role_ids`, `role`, `role: [ ]`. So I don't think it's something as simple as that. No matter what I do, the `can?` check passes. Every time. Without fail.

I've found a lot of stuff out there on CanCan but I can't seem to find this specific thing. Is it because I'm trying to misuse CanCan, and I should be doing this some other way? Or … how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be done in CanCan, as the control granularity of CanCan is on action. So if you really wanna to use CanCan to fulfill your intention, I think you should make the ”role change“ as a method call instead of a form submission.

the controller file

```
class UserController
  def basic
    user.change_role_to_basic
  end

  def premium
    user.change_role_to_premium
  end
end
```

the ability file

```
can :basic, User do
end

can :premium, User do
end
```

Comment: It's not just that simple though, is it? I mean what about this example in their documentation: `can :manage, Project, :group => { :id => user.group_ids }`